# How to filter by a pandas column if the number of unique value in another column is equal a given value

Tags: python, pandas

please I want to filter **AccountID**  that has transaction data for at least `>=3` months ?. This is just a small fraction of the entire dataset

Here is what I did but, I am not sure it is right.

`data = data.groupby('AccountID').apply(lambda x: x['TransactionDate'].nunique() >= 3)`

I get a series as an output with boolean values. I want to get a pandas dataframe

```
       TransactionDate       AccountID  TransactionAmount
0        2020-12-01            8          400000.0
1        2020-12-01           22          25000.0
2        2020-12-02           22          551500.0
3        2020-01-01           17          116.0
4        2020-01-01           24          2000.0
5        2020-01-02           68          6000.0
6        2020-03-03.          20          180000.0
7        2020-03-01           66          34000.0
8        2020-02-01           66          20000.0
9        2020-02-01           66          40600.0
```

The ouput I get

```
AccountID
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregated values for Series with same size like original df, so possible filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
data = data[data.groupby('AccountID')['TransactionDate'].transform('nunique') >= 3]
```

If possible some dates has no same day, `1` use [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for helper column filler by months periods:

```
 s = data.assign(new = data['TransactionDate'].dt.to_period('m')).groupby('AccountID')['new'].transform('nunique')
 data = data[s >= 3]
```